# Laravel 5.4 database migration not working

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I'm new to Laravel and I can't migrate my database. It shows this error how can this be solved

Comment: The issue is with your migration SQL file. The error clearly says a key you're adding is too long. Try to reduce that `email` field's length

Comment: I've downvoted this because (1) there's an image of the error when copy pasting the error was equally simple and (2) there is no relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The known workaround for this issue is:

Open AppServiceProvider and paste:

`Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` within the `public function boot()`

**Note:** Ensure you add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` beneath the namespace.

Then run `php artisan migrate refresh`